# Centos6.3 Rsyslog writes to both custom log and /var/log/messages

Tags: logging, centos, rsyslog

Centos6.3 running rsyslog-5.8.10-6.el6.x86_64 writes to both my custom log file and /var/log/messages.

After making changes to my iptables files to log dropped packets :

-N LOGGING
-A INPUT -j LOGGING
-A OUTPUT -j LOGGING
-A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/sec -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Dropped: " --log-level 4
-A LOGGING -j DROP

I added "kern.warning    /var/log/iptablesDROPPED.log" to the bottom of my /etc/rsyslog.conf file, restarted rsyslog and iptables.

It works great but logs to both files.

PROBLEM: I don't want it logging the same entries to /var/log/messages.

It also happens to ignore my 2 logs/sec rule so I get 3 messages every time it blocks an ssh connection.  The same if I set it to 2/min as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `& ~` after the configuration if you don't want the log messages to go to any other log file.

```
kern.warning /var/log/iptablesDROPPED.log
& stop
```

Comment: As of v7, the discard operator `~` is deprecated. Use `& stop` instead. http://wiki.whyaskwhy.org/Rsyslog#The_stop_directive